# Independence of $\xi$ and $\frac{\xi}{\eta}$

Tags: probability, measure-theory, independence

Let $\xi$ and $\eta$ are independent random variables with densities $\rho_{\xi}$ and $\rho_{\eta}$.
Then $\xi$ and $\frac{\xi}{\eta}$ are independent random variables.

Is it true?
I know theorem which tells that if $\xi$ and $\eta$ are independent then $f(\xi)$ and $g(\eta)$ are independent in case of borel $f$ and $g$.

But I can not find the same proposition for $\xi$ and $f(\xi, \eta)$.

Comment: This is false. What if $\eta$ is almost-surely constant?

Comment: Did you miss an independence assumption on the original rvs?

Comment: @Arkady, yeah, sorry, I really missed it.

Comment: The assumption of $\xi$ and $\eta$ being independent does not change much. The statement is still false.

Comment: @SmallDeviation, then I understood something incorrectly. Like I was reading how to get $\rho_{\frac{\xi}{\eta}}$ and in proof there was the line $\rho_{\xi, \frac{\xi}{\eta}}(u,v) = \rho_{\xi}(u)\rho_\eta(\frac{u}{v})|\frac{u}{v^2}|$. And I thought it is because they are independent and $\rho_{\frac{\xi}{\eta}}$ is equal to $\rho_\eta(\frac{u}{v})|\frac{u}{v^2}|$.

Comment: @perepelart This is due to a substitution. If they were independent, their joint density would factorize into their individual densities.

Comment: @SmallDeviation, Maybe I got it. $\rho_{\xi, \frac{\xi}{\eta}}(u,v)=\rho_{\xi, \eta}(f^{-1}(x, y))|J|=\rho_{\xi,\eta}(u,$$\frac{u}{v})|J|$, there $J$ is just a Jacobian of transformation $f$. And next we just use independence of $\xi$ and $\eta$ and get that we need.

Comment: @SmallDeviation, Am I right now?